# Matlab: wind rose plot: change legend

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

I want to plot a wind rose but my data for the wind speed is very low (0-20). I found the WindRose package here (https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47248-wind-rose) and it gives me the plot. But I can't find anywhere how to change the wind speed values or how to change the legend title. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: what do you mean with change the wind speed values?

Comment: when I plot the data (WR=WindRose(WD,WS);), the wind speed values are put to the default values (0-50,50-100,100-150...). But my values are almost all below 50.

Answer (score 1):

From the [function documentation](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47248-wind-rose) it seems that you can simply set the following two parameters when calling the function.
The first will take your legend title as input.
The second will take the max wind speed. There is another option (`'nspeeds'`) to also set the number of bins desired (i.e.the number intervals between 0 and max wind speed)

```
% PARAMETER          CLASS         DEFAULT VALUE         DESCRIPTION

'lablegend'        String.       'Wind speeds in m/s'  String that will appear at the top of the legend. Can be empty.
'speedround'       Numeric.       [] (auto)            Maximum wind speed will be rounded to the first higher whole multiple of WindSpeedRound.
```